# ngf-before-model-change or ngf-change block the chain to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have a `<div>` element where I can click or drag and drop images. Once I have it in my `ng-model` binded variable I do some elaboration.

Here is the working code.

```
<div class="dragAndDrop"
    ng-model="Image.file"
    ngf-select
    ngf-drop
    ngf-drag-over-class="dragover"
    ngf-accept="'image/*'"
    ngf-max-size="{{Image.sizeLimit}}MB"
    ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
    ngf-model-invalid="Image.invalid"
    ngf-validate-after-resize="true"
    ngf-resize-if="Image.resizeCondition($file)"
    ngf-resize="{ quality: .9, type: 'image/jpeg' }">
```

It takes a few seconds to load and resize the image, meanwhile I would like to show a loading popup. So I tried to use `ngf-before-model-change` and `ngf-change`. They are fired correctly once used but then i found the `$scope.Image.file` variable with `null` value even if the elaboration has finished correctly.

Where is my error? Can't I just associate a function to these 2 events without breaking anything else?

Comment: It probably fails a validation that's why your model is empty.

Comment: You can check `ngf-model-invalid` to see if the invalid file is there.

Comment: @danial it's not there, both `ngf-model-invalid` and `ngf-model` are `null` after the `ngf-change` event is fired